# Indesign: How to get letters as chapter numbers in sub-headings

Tags: adobe-indesign, numbering

I have a book with appendices labeled A, B, C, etc.  I am trying to get sub-headings like A.1, A.2, etc. with a letter in the "chapter number" position.  In InDesign, I have a paragraph style for "Appendix number" like this:

```
 List: Appendices     
 Level: 1
 Format: A, B, C, D
 Number: Appendix ^#
 Mode: Continue from previous
```

This works as expected with the first appendix being "Appendix A" and then "Appendix B" and so on.  The level 2 headings for Appendix A should look like A.1, A.2, etc.

The definition for "Heading 2" is

```
List: Appendices
Level: 2
Format: 1, 2, 3, 4
Number: ^H.^2^t
Mode: Continue from previous
Restart numbers: After any previous level
```

The first Heading 2 in Appendix A is numbered 5.1.  The 5 apparently comes from the fact that this is the fifth entry in a book panel. The "Chapter Number" text variable for this document is "A."

What do I need to do to the get the appendix subheadings to have numbers like A.1, A.2, etc. instead of 5.1, 5.2?

Comment: I don't understand what this is asking.

Comment: @Scott  Thanks!  I've edited the last paragraph to make an explicit question.  Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that does make it more clear. Thanks for the edit. Unfortunately, I don't build indexes this complex. So, I'm no help. `:)` But I'm certain someone else may be able to.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps others, the format for "Heading 2" should be `Number: ^1.^2^t`.  It was the `^H` that was wrong.